# How to set status bar style to light content on iOS7?

Tags: xcode, ios7

I tried several solutions from SO for this problem but none of them worked for me. I created a new iOS7 project with one simple view. I tried setting

```
View controller-based status bar appearance to NO
```

and in AppDelegate:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
```

However this removes the status bar completely.

Without the View controller-based status bar appearance option, Regardless what I set for Status bar style in the plist file, the status bar text is still black. I need it to be white for the entire application. Is this possible?

I am on latest xcode version.

Comment: This happened to me and I fixed it by setting the Status bar is initially hidden to NO in the info.plist additionally to the 2 steps you commented

Answer (score 38, accepted):

did you try it without "Animated:No" ?

Go to Info tab of the project target, Add Row:

UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance, set value NO

Then in appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

This should set it application wide.

Comment: This disables the status bar, it is gone for me.

Comment: I just tried it and worked for me. I am on iOS 7.1 and Xcode 5.1

Comment: Ok it works without storyboard. However when I add a storyboard this does not work anymore.

Comment: Strange. I am using the storyboard and tried it with utility template as well and it changed status bar content on both VCs. Rebooting might help.

Answer (score 27):

The Accepted answer seemed to work sometimes.  I found out that the UIViewController can change the status bar style also.  To get around this and always work, cause I didn't need the UIViewControllers controlling the status bar, I had to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in my `Info.plist`

Comment: You are my new friend. Hi, friend.

Answer (score 21):

Use `needsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` to update status bar in `viewDidLoad:` method of view controller

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Now add below method into view controller:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: Yeah finally that's it - storyboard settings were completely ignored!

Answer (score 3):

I would go with Logan's answer. As of iOS 9, UIApplication's `setStatusBarStyle:` method is deprecated anyway, so you'll want to start moving away from using that. The preferred method, now is to implement `preferredStatusBarStyle` within your `ViewController` like Logan has described.